# How to send random responses on Discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot where you can ping others in the message, and the person you ping gets pinged by the bot. the code will either give me 2 responses, or will give me none when I do commonly suggested methods, like this random response code:

```
const Responses = [
    "image 1",
    "image 2",
    "image 3",
    "image 4",
    "image 5"
];

const Response = Math.floor(Math.random() * Responses.length);

console.log(Responses[Response])
```

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'throw',
    description: "this is a throw command!",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} threw a potato at ${message.mentions.users.first() ?? "everyone"}!`);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is doing it twice because you have a repetitive line. `message.channel.send(\`${message.author} threw a potato at ${message.mentions.users.first() ?? "everyone"}!\`);` exists twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a helper function to pick one random element from an array and using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) include it in your message like this:

```js
function pickOneFrom(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

module.exports = {
  name: 'throw',
  description: 'this is a throw command!',
  execute(message, args) {
    const responses = ['apple', 'melon', 'potato', 'snowball', 'spanner'];

    message.channel.send(
      `${message.author} threw a ${pickOneFrom(responses)} at ${
        message.mentions.users.first() ?? 'everyone'
      }!`,
    );
  },
};
```

[image]